# Microservices handeling events from redis pubsub

Tags: java, redis, microservices

I am trying to create a microservice that listen to a redis pubsub channel and persist some events into a DB.

In my test case i am spinning up 2 instances of my microservice both listening to the same channel.

the thing that i am facing now is that for every events received both instances update the DB at the same time and i wanted to know if there are ways to prevent this action?

like for every events one instance will be elected to perform the update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two kinds of messaging system: `pub-sub` and `queue`. For a `pub-sub` system, every client processes all events, while for a `queue` system, each event is processed by only one client. It seems **what you need is a `queue`, NOT `pub-sub`**.

You can use a Redis `LIST` to implement a simple messaging `queue`:

```
// producers push events into a queue
RPUSH que event1
RPUSH que event2
// push other events...

// consumers pop events from the queue
BLPOP que timeout
```

**NOTE**: this is **NOT** a perfect solution, it has some reliable problems. However, there're some open-source solutions based on Redis, you don't need to reinvent the wheel.